# Объединение полей таблицы базы данных в одно поле

Tags: база-данных, mysql, postgresql, sql

Есть следующая структура данных

```
Школа
- Количество учеников
- Класс
  - Количество учеников в классе
Школа
- Количество учеников
- Класс
  - Количество учеников в классе
- Класс
  - Количество учеников в классе
```

При этом в процессе использования базы данных необходимо делать выборку по значению "Количество учеников", а выборку по классам делать не требуется, более того, данные о классах всегда используются для каждой из школ как единое целое. То есть

```
Школа
- Количество учеников
// ******************************
// Начало единой структуры данных
- Класс
  - Количество учеников в классе
- Класс
  - Количество учеников в классе
- Класс
  - Количество учеников в классе
// Конец единой структуры данных
// ******************************
```

Возникает два возможных варианта:

1. Создать отдельную таблицу для классов.
2. Создать единое поле для классов и поместить туда данных в специальном формате, например, JSON.

Во втором случае, база перестает быть реляционной в чистом виде, но схема упрощается и доступ к данным ускоряется (нужно делать меньше SQL).

Какие плюсы и минусы двух подходов возможны?

---

То есть было

```
таблица Школы
таблица Классы
```

Стало

```
таблица Школы
```

Где есть столбец Классы, содержащий JSON, в котором для каждой школы теперь хранятся те данные, которые были раньше были в таблице Классы.

Comment: почитайте о нормальных формах реляционной БД. приведение таблицы к форме (какой именно уже не помню) подразумевает что она не содержит данные которые можно подсчитать. 
на вашем примере это означает следующее: что в таблице школа нет смысл хранить количество учеников так как эта информация легко вычисляется по таблице. 
если ваша БД содержит информацию о учениках тогда в таблице класс нет смысла хранить количество учеников. так как эту информацию тоже можно подсчитать.

если вы не можете самостоятельно спроэктировать БД задайте вопрос "как спроэктировать БД" + список требований к ней

Answer (score 4):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, точнее не совсем понятно, что нужно получить на выходе.
Чем не устраивает структура

```
| school | class | amount |
```

где, school - номер школы, class - класс, amount - количество учеников в классе.

Для выбора общего количества учеников в разрезе школ будем использовать запрос:

```
 SELECT school, SUM(amount) FROM
 tablename GROUP BY school
```

Для выбора количества учеников школы в разрезе классов запрос:

```
 SELECT class, amount FROM tablename WHERE school=some_value
```

Comment: Идея сводится к отказу от жесткой схемы базы данных. То есть вместо таблицы, связанной с набором других таблиц внешними ключами, получаем одну таблицу. При этом мы теряем возможность использовать SQL при поиске по частям документа (он становится единым целым), но приобретаем гибкость и простоту (структуру документа можно менять, не меняя схемы базы данных, и таблиц становится меньше), более того, сами документы можно вынести из реляционной базы и перенести в базу типа ключ-значение.

Comment: Тут все зависит от набора операций, которые Вам нужно будет выполнять.
Например, посчитать количество учеников в школе, изменить количество учеников в классе, инкрементировать класс (перевести всех учеников в следующий класс)...
В подходе с текстовым полем, в котором хранить информацию в виде JSON (или в любом другом виде) эта задача уже не кажется такой тривиальной.
Запросы станут непонятными, а код сложным для восприятия.

Comment: Хотя, снова таки, все относительно. У каждого свой стиль. Но имея в руках такое мощное оружие как mysql, считаю нужно использовать его возможности на полную

Answer (score 2):

Задача, так как она у вас написанна - SQL вообще не требует. Вы можете для каждого класса создать отделный файл и в нем хранить JSON-структуру - сухо и комфортно.

Вам всё равно прийдется для любой операции распаковывать JSON, менять и паковать обратно. Что вы будете читать/писать БД, что файл - одинаково (хотя на файлах возможно будет шустрее на пару процентов).

Если же делать именно БД, то у вас должна быть структура типа:

```
Школы -> Классы -> Ученики.
```

В таблице "классы" ссылочное поле на "школу", в таблице "ученики" - ссылка на "класс".

Все манипуляции просты и прозрачны. Самый сложный запрос содержит два join. Будет ли это работать быстрее чем JSON - однозначно, особенно на задачах "посчитать всех учеников школы", "узнать сколько ивановых у нас в школе", "перевести Васю из 5а в 5б".

Писать "на тему" можно фолиантами - что не понятно или интересно - пишите вопросы.

Comment: Если школа одна, то таблица "Школы" может быть отброшена.